# How to used Event based approach in Two Application Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, events, event-handling

I am very new to Spring Event based approach i.e @EventListener approach to publish Event from some where and handle other place of code.

I have implemented this approach in Spring boot Single Project i.e Order created one place publish event and handle event in other place of same project. But I want to maintain the two application with same approach i.e Event Publish in one application but Event Listener in second application.

Can any one please guide me how this will be possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send events between two different application it is impossible to use Events. You need to use [JMS](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html) which allows you send events betweend different applications in Java.

If you are talking about two instances of same application simply use normal [Event](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2) approach.

Comment: can you clarify why it is impossible to use Event approach for two different applications? Why does it work for only two instances of same application?